# where in the pod config can I use the defined environment variable with $(x)

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables

According to https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/#using-environment-variables-inside-of-your-config environment variables (defined in the config) can be used in the config like this:

```
...
spec:
  containers:
    env:
    - name: GREETING
      value: "Warm greetings to"
    ...
    args: ["$(GREETING) $(HONORIFIC) $(NAME)"]
```

Can I use the variables everywhere in the config? (Probably only in side container.)

This seems not to work:

```
    env:
    - name: DBHOST
      valueFrom:
        configMapKeyRef:
          key: db-host
          name: db-config
    - name: DB_URL
      value: mysql://$(DBHOST)/my_database
```

In the container, `echo $DB_URL` showed `mysql://$(DBHOST)/my_database`, but I expected DBHOST to be replaced.

So does it work in all other places except in `env`?

Maybe I have to look for another possibility to concatenate the values from the config map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [detailed API documentation for a Container object](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#container-v1-core), some of the fields specifically call out

> Variable references $(VAR_NAME) are expanded using the container's environment.

This is specifically documented for `args` and `command`.  Similar text is also in the documentation for [EnvVar](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#envvar-v1-core)'s `value`, with the caveat there that "references $(VAR_NAME) are expanded using the previous defined environment variables" (order of the `env:` block matters).

In a couple of places you can also exec a command inside a container.  This includes `postStart` and `preStop` hooks and probes.  These ultimately become an [ExecAction](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#execaction-v1-core) API object.  The command there is documented to not run inside a shell and can't directly use the `$(VAR_NAME)` syntax, but if you do run a shell explicitly, it should be able to use container-level environment variables.  (If your `command:` or Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT` sets environment variables, these will not be visible, similar to `docker exec`.)

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata: {name: for-example}
spec:
  containers:
    - name: for-example
      env:
        - name: VAR_NAME
          value: a concrete string
        - name: COPY_OF_VAR_NAME
          value: '$(VAR_NAME)'
      command:
        - /bin/echo
        - '$(VAR_NAME)'
      args:
        - '$(VAR_NAME), again'
      livenessProbe:
        exec:
          command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - echo $VAR_NAME gets expanded by the shell
      lifecycle:
        postStart:
          exec:
            command:
              - /bin/sh
              - -c
              - echo $VAR_NAME gets expanded by the shell
```

Comment: (Based on the documentation I quoted, I expect your `$(DB_URL)` variable to be expanded correctly, since the `configMapKeyRef` is not `optional: true`.)

Comment: You are right, it works. When doing tests with a simplified example, I realized that order of the env: block matters. I have changed the order by accident when editing in an UI, so I did not include the correct order in the example.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, as stated in the docs f.e. here [Define Dependent Environment Variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-interdependent-environment-variables/) only SERVICE_ADDRESS can be correctly resolved using due to the wrong order in env section.